# Android background Service to check location services is on or off

Tags: android, service

I am looking for a background service that checks when the location services is on or off.

Comment: please post your code what u have done till now

Comment: Didn't downvote, but this "question" (where is the question?) does not show any research effort. It is unclear and not useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen location updates using `FusedLocationClient`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (requestingLocationUpdates) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

private void startLocationUpdates() {
    fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
            locationCallback,
            Looper.getMainLooper());
}

  locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            if (locationResult == null) {
                return;
            }
            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                // Update UI with location data
                // ...
            }
        };
    };
```

Comment: i have already done this but i want a service with broadcast receiver which detects the mobile GPS on and off state.